# Ruby's `find` method won't work on code block that returns an array. Gets a NilClass error

Tags: ruby, cucumber

My question involves Ruby's `find` method and why it works in one situation but not in another. NOTE: I'm using this method in a Cucumber step definition written in Ruby.

This code block works the way I want it to:

```
Then(/^I expect the bolt service children for CrossrefDepositsDaf to include only: IngestUpdateWorkflow$/) do
  @boltworkflowservice ||= BoltWorkflowService.new
  Watir::Wait.until(60) do
    @job_family = @boltworkflowservice.get_workflows_job_family(@job_id).json
    @job_family.find { |job| job['type'] == "IngestUpdateWorkflow" }
  end
  expect(@job_family.find{|job| job['type'] == "IngestUpdateWorkflow"}.nil?).to eq(false), "IngestUpdateWorkflow child not found"
end
```

But I wanted to rewrite this code block to get rid of the instance variable and reduce the block by one line. I tried the following:

```
Then(/^I expect the bolt service children for CrossrefDepositsDaf to include only: IngestUpdateWorkflow$/) do
  @boltworkflowservice ||= BoltWorkflowService.new
  Watir::Wait.until(60) do
    puts @boltworkflowservice.get_workflows_job_family(@job_id).json
    @boltworkflowservice.get_workflows_job_family(@job_id).json.find {|job| job['type'] == "IngestUpdateWorkflow"}
  end
  expect(@job_family.find{|job| job['type'] == "IngestUpdateWorkflow"}.nil?).to eq(false), "IngestUpdateWorkflow child not found"
end
```

I just added the `puts` to see what the code would return. According to the `puts`, it returns an array that contains three hash objects but I still get an error. Here is what I get when I try to run the second block:

```
[{"id"=>914295, "type"=>"CrossrefDepositsDaf", "subType"=>"", "parentId"=>0, "state"=>"SUCCESS", "subState"=>"SUCCESS", "dataPointer"=>"s3://sequoia-install/app-resources/test.cirrostratus.org/workflows/CrossrefDepositsDaf/2015/7/29/148c7ebc-3da4-4650-a22e-2e8962d448fc", "created"=>"2015-07-29 01:58:14", "metadata"=>[]}, {"id"=>914296, "type"=>"CrossRefDeposits", "subType"=>"BoltCatDaf", "parentId"=>914295, "state"=>"SUCCESS", "subState"=>"SUCCESS", "dataPointer"=>"s3://sequoia-install/app-resources/test.cirrostratus.org/workflows/CrossRefDeposits/2015/7/29/3a703736-d4a2-456e-baa9-7bf2c0f4a0e2", "created"=>"2015-07-29 01:58:17", "metadata"=>[]}, {"id"=>914297, "type"=>"IngestUpdateWorkflow", "subType"=>"CrossRefDeposits", "parentId"=>914296, "state"=>"SUCCESS", "subState"=>"CREATED", "dataPointer"=>"s3://sequoia-install/app-resources/test.cirrostratus.org/workflows/IngestUpdateWorkflow/2015/7/29/9282591b-f93c-49d6-b656-4afbd14156ef", "created"=>"2015-07-29 01:58:23", "metadata"=>[]}]

NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass
./features/step_definitions/catdaf_integration_crossref_deposits_steps.rb:42:in `/^I expect the bolt service children for CrossrefDepositsDaf to include only: IngestUpdateWorkflow$/'
C:\Users\Dugan23\workspace\cloudy_clouds\cucumber\features\content_management\daf\integration\crossref_deposits.feature:11:in `And I expect the bolt service children for CrossrefDepositsDaf to include only: IngestUpdateWorkflow'
1 scenario (1 failed)
6 steps (1 failed, 5 passed)
9m30.221s

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can somebody please explain to me why the second block of code doesn't work? The `puts` shows that I should be feeding the `find` method an array so why does it say that I"m trying to run the `find` method on a `nil:NilClass`. Thank you in advance for any and all of your help.

NOTE: When I added a `puts` statement to the first block of code to print out `@job_family` it returned the same exact array as the second block of code. Does this mean that in the second block of code Ruby is trying to run the `find` method before evaluating the code before it? I tried to remedy this by adding parentheses as follows, but to no avail:

```
(@boltworkflowservice.get_workflows_job_family(@job_id).json).find {|job| job['type'] == "IngestUpdateWorkflow"}
```

Comment: Since your question doesn't have to involve Cucumber can you simplify it and ask ?

Comment: @limekin Answered the question. I'm a little embarrassed that I overlooked that. That was definitely the issue. How can I give you points for answering the question?

Comment: Yeah I think I will move it to an answer. I just wanted to clarify, because I thought you might have `@job_family` defined somewhere else.

Comment: Note that every time you use an `@variable` in a cucumber step definition you are creating a global variable that exists for the whole execution time of the scenario. At the very least `@job_family` should be job_family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second version, you have avoided using @job_family inside the block, but still you are referring to it on the expect, which obviously would be nil unless you have defined it elsewhere